# Changing the view in TabHost in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How Can i change the TabHost in android, so it should look same as UITabBarController in iPhone? ie view should be on the top of the TabHost,not at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample layout code to have the tabs on the bottom of the screen:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0"></TabWidget>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```