# How twitter has implemented the bottom bar for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can any one point me to UI Guidelines/how to for twitter bottom bar

[image: here is the attached]

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Can you briefly explain your problem so that we can understand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following guide to learn about custom tab widgets styles:

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

if you want to put the tabs at the bottom of the screen look at this answer:

[Changing the view in TabHost in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978079/changing-the-view-in-tabhost-in-android/5978503#5978503)

Comment: are you sure twitter uses tabhost for bottom bar, just to make sure.

Comment: After a look at the twitter app, I'd say that the one in the image you posted seems an Action Bar, it is at the bottom of a tweet screen, the other one in the twitter app at the top is a tab widget. You can take a look a this component to build your Action Bar: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar